# kind cluster is not deleting, how to fix that?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to delete kind cluster using.

```
kind delete cluster --name samples
```

And I got error after waiting for 15 min.

```
Deleting cluster "samples" ...
ERROR: failed to delete cluster "samples": failed to delete nodes: command "docker rm -f -v samples-control-plane" failed with error: exit status 1
Command Output: Error response from daemon: removal of container samples-control-plane is already in progress
```

But this is the only command I ran to delete, not before.

So tried to delete the container of kind cluster using.

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
  NAMES
5d0fa7222662   postgres:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   51 minutes ago   Up 51 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   postgres_database
e6acb3781680   kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   33 hours ago     Up 2 hours      127.0.0.1:44151->6443/tcp
  samples-control-plane
```

And tried deleting stopping it first.

```
docker stop e6
```

But stuck there for almost an hour but no response till now.

So I pressed ctrl+c and ran the command with -t.

```
docker stop e6 -t 2
```

Same result, stuck there and kept for 3 hours and more, but still there only. How to delete this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you described most likely has to do with the docker bug. There are many threads on github related to this situation:

- [Failed to delete cluster](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/708):

> that looks like a docker bug, there was at least one previous bug like this where containers would get in a partially removed state and the only fix was manually removing them w/o docker. looking for current issues upstream.

- [Running kind delete cluster has issue deleting linked containers](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1116):

> Potentally fiexed in [this topic](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/pull/1117).

- [Removal In Progress](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3434):

> Hm, I don't think this is a  `docker-compose`  issue. However, the way I would proceed is
>
> 1. Stop the docker daemon (`sudo service docker stop`)
> 2. Remove the remaining container files  `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/9adaaacc30d3<TAB>`
> 3. Start the docker daemon (`sudo service docker start`).

**Solution / workaround:**

Try to restart the docker daemon and do a `docker system prune -a`.

Answer (score 0):

my environment:
windows 10 + wsl2 + ubuntu 20
the following worked for me

```
kind delete clusters CLUSTERNAME
```

Comment: This worked also on linux even if it's not in the official documentation of kind. 
The suggested `kind delete cluster --name <clustername>` from the documentation did not delete the docker containers. This one did.